# Minted does not detect functions and methods declared in other files

Tags: minted, pygments

I am working with minted to make a C Language book.
Functions declared after keyword void are correctly identified and styled.
When I am calling functions from other files it classifies them as variables.
The file where TI_NewTimer is declared is included in the directory as well.

How can I make it work? Meaning having TI_NewTimer in pink?

Thank you.

Minimal working example:

```
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{my-bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\setminted[C]{
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    mathescape=true,
    linenos=true,
    numbersep=5pt,
    style=vs,
    bgcolor=my-bg
    }
\begin{document} 

\inputminted{C}{Test.c}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example in tex code?

Comment: @Sebastiano added

Comment: we can not run the example so it can not be used to see the issue or test answers. Do you mean that if you call `POL_init` it is a different color to `TI_NewTimer` ? Are you sure the declartion being in other files makes any difference? I'd be surprised, the pygments lexer doesn't usually carry that much context.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point, if I call POL_Init in the same file it does not show it in pink. It looks like it only detects it as function if it goes after the word void ...

Comment: or rather it detects function _declarations_ not function calls